# Enable/Find logging for Dynamics AX Odata service

Tags: logging, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm trying to connect an external system to AX using the OdataQueryService. Connecting with Excel gives the correct results from the server, however I get an error when using the external system.

Is there some logging on the Dynamics AX Odata service that I can enable for troubleshooting?

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: 
Use Service Configuration Editor to edit ax32serv.exe.config. 
Enable MessageLogging and Enable tracing. 
Change logging path + save 
Restart AOS Generate some traffic 
Analyze Ax32Serv_messages.svclog and Ax32Serv_tracing.svclog with Microsoft Service Trace Viewer.